# How do i tunnel from local to external apache

Tags: apache, ssh, putty, tunneling

I'm trying to set up a ssh tunnel using putty so i can view websites which are at my work location. The remote development server (apache) does not accept any incoming calls on port 80, so i'm trying to tunnel through ssh which should work since i'm able to login to my shell account.

I'm using putty 0.60, In my settings ive added a new rule at connection -> tunnels
Ive added source port 80, Destination: remote.domain:80, i tried setting the radio buttons to local, remote, dynamic and the 2nd line to auto, still doesnt seem to work.

Do i need to add something to my windows host file to make apache accept the request?
Any idea's?

Comment: SSH is listening on port 22 while apache normally listening on port 80, what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Destination should be `localhost:80`. This is where the remote port is forwarded to.

Then in your `hosts` file reroute `remote.domain` to 127.0.0.1.

That should give you access.

Comment: Note that a web server can serve different pages depending on domain name; while you can mess with your local `hosts` file to that effect, making a SOCKSified tunnel handles this more gracefully.

Comment: Nice got it working now! Thx goreSplatter. I was assuming that destination would be the remote domain, thats where my thinking went wrong.